# Element type(long) without content

Tags: xml, wsdl, xsd, xsd-validation

**My schema is:**

```
 <xsd:element name="SetMonitor">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="period" type="xsd:long" />
            <xsd:element name="refreshrate" type="xsd:long" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

**And my xml will be:**

***Case 1.***

```
<SetMonitor
    xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:cb="http://schemas.cordys.com/1.0/coboc">
    <period/>
    <refreshrate/>
</SetMonitor>
```

**OR**
***Case 2.***

```
 <SetMonitor
        xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
        xmlns:cb="http://schemas.cordys.com/1.0/coboc">
        <period>10</period>
        <refreshrate>20</refreshrate>
    </SetMonitor>
```

For **case 2** there are no issues. But for **case 1** I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXException: cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: '' is not a valid value for 'integer'.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 6; columnNumber: 14; cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: '' is not a valid value for 'integer'.
```

How can i modify the wsdl so that it accepts both **case 1** and **case 2**?
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
    <xsd:element name="SetMonitor">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="period" type="xsd:long"  nillable="true"/>
                <xsd:element name="refreshrate" type="xsd:long" nillable="true"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
```

And construct xml with "empty" element in this way

```
<SetMonitor xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <period>2147483647</period>
    <refreshrate xsi:nil="true" />
</SetMonitor>
```

Or you could modify the type of element using pattern, something like this

```
<xsd:element name="period">
    <xsd:simpleType>
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:pattern value="|([1-9][0-9]*)" />
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:element>
```

(the pattern has to be define more precisly, than I use for this example)

Another possibility could be to define simpleType for empty string

```
<xsd:simpleType name="emptyString">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:length value="0"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

and then define your element as union of xsd:long and emptyString type

```
<xsd:element name="period">
    <xsd:simpleType>
        <xsd:union memberTypes="xsd:long emptyString"/>
    </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:element>
```

Comment: I tried modifying the wsdl as mentioned above(the one at top). But I faced the new issue, something like `Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'cb:SetMonitor' is not complete. One of '{"http://schemas.cordys.com/1.0/coboc":period}' is expected.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 4; columnNumber: 3; cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'cb:SetMonitor' is not complete. One of '{"http://schemas.cordys.com/1.0/coboc":period}' is expected.`  And if I put moiOccurs='0' for **period** and **refreshrate** then it works.

Comment: It means that `<refreshrate xsi:nil="true" />` from xml is not mapping the `<xsd:element name="refreshrate" type="xsd:long" nillable="true"/>` .

Comment: `minOccurs="0"` means an optional element (it can be omitted). `nillable="true"` means it is still required to have this element in xml but you can mark it as `xsi:nil="true"` (something like "null" in other languages)

Comment: I got your point and thanks for reply.
But I am facing the above mentioned issue with proposed solution.

Comment: Could you give an example of xml causing the issue you mentioned?

Comment: `<SetMonitor xmlns="http://schemas.cordys.com/1.0/coboc">
 <period xsi:nil="true"/>
 <refreshrate xsi:nil="true"/>
</SetMonitor>`

Is the xml causing the issue with proposed solution(one at the top).

Comment: This `<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://schemas.cordys.com/1.0/coboc" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
<xsd:element name="SetMonitor"> <xsd:complexType> <xsd:sequence> <xsd:element name="period" type="xsd:long" nillable="true"/>
<xsd:element name="refreshrate" type="xsd:long" nillable="true"/>
</xsd:sequence> </xsd:complexType> </xsd:element> </xsd:schema>` validates your xml example. Could you try it?

Comment: This is what I had tried earlier. I don't know why it is not working.
Is it because we are not defining nameSpace for **xsi** as we are using **xsi:nil="true"**? Should we declare it and what would be that?

Comment: It might be (although I would expect another error message). Try add `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` declaration to your xml.

Comment: It now just passed my WSDL validation. Thank you.