# How to accept xsd vs xml validation when elements having null values

Tags: java, xml, validation, parsing, jaxb

I have a xml and have to validate against xsd for the structure and data type. but Some fields in the xml has null/empty values. But when using JAXB for validating the xml

> `"cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: '' is not a valid value for 'integer'."`

This exception is thrown from JAXB exception with linked SaxParserError Exception. But I have to accept the xml with null values. These threads
[validating an XML schema with empty attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629041/validating-an-xml-schema-with-empty-attributes) and  [Element type(long) without content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17313022/element-typelong-without-content) shows we have to modify the xml with respect to xsd such that it should accept the null/empty values.

Is there any other way that I can override the methods of  ValidationHandler class and Unmarshaller class to accept null values.

Comment: What does the schema definition look like for the element that is failing?

Comment: What is a "null" value in XML? If your XSD dictates an element to by of type `xs:integer`, then an empty value in that element is invalid. There is no way around that. You could make the element optional (`minOccurs="0"`) and completely omit it in the XML. But at the end, the producing side should change, if it produces such empty elements.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I have made the minoccurs=0. But still throws the error. "cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: '' is not a valid value for 'integer'. Null means empty.  Yes empty is invalid. But how to accept. I doesnt want to change the XML pattern for this action. Is there any way around?

Comment: Errrrm ... Was it so ambiguous when I said "There is no way around that"? Additionally, when declaring `minOccurs="0"` that means that the element can be omitted. If it is there, it still must not be empty. This is the purpose of an XSD. If you don't want to have your XML conform to that XSD, then just don't validate it!

Comment: Do you tried nillable option for your element? [see here](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_element.asp)

Comment: @Xstian yeah but I have to change the xml as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I guess you tried to put

```
<myinteger></myinteger>
```

in your XML but have an XSD like:

```
<element name="myinteger" type="integer" />
```

or

```
<element minOccurs="0" name="myinteger" type="integer" />
```

JAXB is right. In terms of XSD validation, this is wrong so you either have to change the XML, change the XSD, or disable validation (will still be wrong but won't crash). `MinOccurs="0"` means it is accepted that the element is not present at all (remove all the myinteger tags). It doesn't mean that a tag with empty content is accepted. The content must be integer. Empty string is not an integer.

Setting nillable = true doesn't work either. It means that this would be accepted :

```
<myinteger xsi:nil="true"></myinteger>
```

But you have to add this xsi:nil="true".

If you do want to accept this:

```
<myinteger></myinteger>
```

You can change your XSD as below:

```
<element name="myinteger" type="IntegerOrNothing" />

<xsd:simpleType name="IntegerOrNoting">
    <xsd:union memberTypes="xsd:integer">
        <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                <xsd:enumeration value="" />
            </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:simpleType>
    </xsd:union>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

If you generate your beans from the XSD with Jaxb, fields of this type will be of type `String` by default. You will then need to use custom bindings to get Integer fields.

Comment: And one more thing my xml which has data which delcared as integer has string or char values which takes it has null. How to validate without the xsd in jaxb

Comment: I don't understand what is your question here?